# jQuery.vticker.js mouseleave, mouseenter functions problems

Tags: jquery, bind, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am developing a website with a news scroll up or blind effect in a strip. Scenario is when user will mouse hover on a news item then a popbox will open.

Everything is going fine with the codes i wrote:

```
    if(options.mousePause)
    {
        obj.bind("mouseenter",function(){
            options.isPaused = true;
            $Box.css('width',200);
            obj.children('ul').children('li').css('background','#f0f0f0');
            obj.children('ul').children('li').children('a').css('color','#000');
            var offset = obj.children('ul').children('li').offset();
            $Box.css('left', offset.left);
            $Box.css('top', offset.top+25);
            $Box.css('display','block');
        }).bind("mouseleave",function(){

            $Box.hover(function(){
                options.isPaused = true;
            },function() { 
                options.isPaused = false;
                $Box.css('display','none');
                obj.children('ul').children('li').css('background','transparent');
                obj.children('ul').children('li').children('a').css('color','#ffe300');
            });

            options.isPaused = false;
            $Box.css('display','none');
            obj.children('ul').children('li').css('background','transparent');
            obj.children('ul').children('li').children('a').css('color','#ffe300');
        }); // mouseleave function end
```

Everything is fine but when i hover on a news item box is displaying but i am not able to hover over the box, as mouse pointer leave the news strip, the vticker.js function mouseleave called and box is again disappear.

Please check this page live http://tagbees.designforce.us/ and please give me advise to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for Ori and Syed Salman Akbar for being concerned and tried to help me. I tried both methods of Ori and one logic of Syed Salman akbar but in vain. I also tried many other options and finally i got it.

The problem was not in strip LI "mouseleave" function that was and is working fine. when mouseleave the li function is repainting/restore the LI color and background with setting the $Box.css('display','none');

I've made the following changes in the codes.

1. In my question, the popup box hover function codes were nested in "mouseleave" function of LI. I put the $Box.hover function out from LI "mouseleave" function.
2. Binded the "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" functions with the $Box as it is a seperate object from strip.
3. On $Box "mouseenter" function added the codes to repaint the strip LI to make the feel as LI is still hovering and restoring/repainting the LI on "mouseleave" function of the $Box.

have a look the new codes:

```
    if(options.mousePause)
    {
        obj.bind("mouseenter",function(){
            options.isPaused = true;
            $Box.css('width',200);
            obj.children('ul').children('li').css('background','#f0f0f0');
            obj.children('ul').children('li').children('a').css('color','#000');
            var offset = obj.children('ul').children('li').offset();
            $Box.css('left', offset.left);
            $Box.css('top', offset.top+25);
            $Box.css('display','block');
        }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
            options.isPaused = false;
            $Box.css('display','none');
            obj.children('ul').children('li').css('background','transparent');
            obj.children('ul').children('li').children('a').css('color','#ffe300');
        }); // mouseleave function end
    } // if end
    $Box.bind("mouseenter",function(){
        options.isPaused = true;
        isBoxHover = true;
            $Box.css('width',200);
            obj.children('ul').children('li').css('background','#f0f0f0');
            obj.children('ul').children('li').children('a').css('color','#000');
            var offset = obj.children('ul').children('li').offset();
            $Box.css('left', offset.left);
            $Box.css('top', offset.top+25);
            $Box.css('display','block');

    }).bind("mouseleave",function() { 
        options.isPaused = false;
        isBoxHover = false;
        $Box.css('display','none');
        obj.children('ul').children('li').css('background','transparent');
        obj.children('ul').children('li').children('a').css('color','#ffe300');
    });
```

and now its working fine for me. You can see the result by visiting the page: http://tagbees.designforce.us/

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options:

### option 1

Wrap your `.Scroller` and `.tickPop` elements in another element, and bind the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events on the wrapper. In the `mouseover` you check:

- if the event target is a `.Scroller` item (`li`) then open or update the `.tickPop`
- if the event target is `.tickPop`, do nothing
- otherwise, close the `.tickPop`
  And in `mouseleave` you know that the mouse has left the entire container, so you close the `.tickBox`.

### option 2

Add a little `setTimeout` to the closing of `.tickPop` on `mouseleave`, and call `clearTimeout` if the mouse enters `.tickBox` or a `.Scroller` item.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global boolean variable "DisplayPopup". default value false
Only in mouse hover and mouse enter of news strip and every child item of news strip set "DisplayPopup"=true and also make sure that if "DisplayPopup" is set to "true" you do not change its value.
now in the mouse hover, mouse enter and mouse leave of the news strip and every child item of news strip make sure that popup is set to visible if "DisplayPopup"=true.

now to close the popup you can have two options

1. close button. behind this close button set "DisplayPopup"=false
2. on mouse leave of popup set "DisplayPopup"=false and close popup.

Also ensure that popup is not child item of news strip. it is just displayed below it.